# Is this the correct way to do an Editor Template?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I would like to know know if I am doing an editor template correctly. And If I am doing it incorrectly, can you point me in the right direction to do it properly.

My Editor Template for a textarea:

```
    @modeltype IEnumerable(Of be_PostTag)

@code
    If Model Is Nothing Then
     @Html.TextArea("PostTags")    
   Else
     Dim sb As New StringBuilder    
    For Each x In Model
        Dim tags = x.Tag & IIf(x.Equals(Model.Last), "", ", ")
        sb.Append(tags)
    Next    
    @Html.TextArea("PostTags", sb.ToString, 10, 50, Nothing)
  End If
End Code
```

**Edit:** I see various posts on SO that suggest using the TextAreaFor helper instead of the non-For control(s) so that one can take advantage of model binding. But when I try to use TextAreFor, VS2013  complains that it is not accessible. I will need to post the PostTags back to the server and save them to the database when a post is made or edited. Hope this helps.

Comment: It would perhaps be more instructive if you asked about the problem you're actually trying to solve (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whether or not what you have here is a correct or good approach depends largely on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I added some more info above.

Comment: `TextArea()` and `TextAreaFor()` bind to a property but you model is a collection. Are you wanting a text area for each item in your collection, or to combine all you items to one `string` value and display a text area for that value?

Comment: Combine into a string and display all values separated by commas. And this works now because when edit an article i have the tags in the textarea all separated by commas. But I just want to be sure this is an acceptable approach.

Comment: A better way would be to create the 'comma separated string' in the controller which you can do with `string yourCombinedString = string.Join(",",yourListOfStrings);`  and just use `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.yourCombinedString)` (no `EditorTemplate` required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guidance to use the `Html.*For` style helpers is so that you can stay strongly-typed. If you use something like `Html.TextBox("Foo")`, and later get rid of or change the name of your `Foo` property, the view will happily keep rendering the input for `Foo`, regardless. But, if you use `Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Foo)`, then Intellisense will show you there's a problem.

However, the `For` helpers, don't tend to play well with editor templates, simply because the context of what's the "model" changes inside an editor template. You're now working with just the property, not the complete model your view had. Here it's actually better to use the non-`For` helpers and pass an empty string as the property name, i.e.:

```
@Html.TextBox("")
```

Razor will contextually fill the right value for you.

In your particular scenario here, though. An editor template is a poor choice. First, they're not really meant to contend with enumerables. You can use `Html.EditorFor` on an enumerable, but what it really does is inspect the inner type and render an editor template for that type for each item in the enumerable, not one template for the entire enumerable property, itself. Also, as Stephen Muecke pointed out in the comments, it would be far better to combine the string, first, and then pass that combined string to your view. This is where view models come in handy, because you can create something like the following:

```
Public Class FooViewModel

    Public Property Tags As IEnumerable(Of be_PostTag)

    Public Property TagsAsString As String
        Get
            Return String.Join(",", Tags.Select(Function(x) x.Tag))
        End Get

        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            Tags = Value.Split(",").Select(Function(x) New be_PostTag With { .Tag = x })
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function (x) x.TagsAsString)
```

A few caveats. I'm a C# guy, so take that code with a grain of salt. For what it's worth, VB.NET is dropping in popularity fast, and even more so in conjunction with ASP.NET MVC. For your own edification, I'd recommend picking up C#, and especially when you have problems, you'll find better and more helpful answers as the pool of ASP.NET MVC C# developers that can help you is *much* larger.